# CRM 2013: Deserializing within a sandboxed plugin

Tags: plugins, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an XML string that I would like to deserialize into a strongly typed class.  The below code works great until I put it into a sandboxed plugin, at which point I get a FileIOPermissions error because I am using the StringReader class.  I am having issues trying to deserialize without using StringReader.  Does anyone have a good alternative?

```
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(configurationWebResource.Attributes["content"].ToString());
resourceContent = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(binary);

DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ViewSecurityConfiguration));

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(resourceContent))
{
    using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
    {
        if (serializer.IsStartObject(xmlReader))   //Throws FileIOPermissions error
        {
            currentViewSecurityConfiguration = (ViewSecurityConfiguration)(serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following which I've run successfully in a sandbox plugin:

```
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(configurationWebResource.Attributes["content"].ToString());
resourceContent = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(binary);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ViewSecurityConfiguration));

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(resourceContent))
{
    currentViewSecurityConfiguration = (ViewSecurityConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the XmlSerializer class because my ViewSecurityConfiguration class utilizes IDictionary.  Rather than re-write my implementation to work with XmlSerializer I think I will find or write a custom generic Xml Serializing class.  Despite that I think that this is in essence the answer to my question since it shows how developers usually deserialize within a sandboxed plugin.